# Using static variables from util class in map-reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, static, mapreduce

I have a mapper and reducer and a util class.

```
- The util class has a static class variable int a=0 
  and a static method doSomething() which calls another static method 
  add() which increment a by 1.
- I call the UtilClass.doSomething() from the reducer.
- When I try to print the final value of "a" in 
  doSomething() using 
  context.getCounter("doSomethign method","value of a").increment(1);,
  the value says 1229 which is weird since the reduce task received only 240 keys
- A total of 30 reducers are spawned.
```

Below is a sample code block. I'm avoiding some boilerplate code.
NOTE: This is run in a distributed manner and not standalone.

```
class MyMapper extends Reducer{
 public reduce(<params>){
   UtilClass.doSomething(context);
 }
}

class UtilClass{
  public static int a=0;
  public static void add(){
    a=a+1;
  }
  public static void doSomething(Reducer.Context context){
    add();
    // This is printing 1229 in the end, instead of 240 which is the number of key given to the reducer
    context.getCounter("doSomethign method","value of a").increment(1);
  }
}
```

This leads me to the following questions

1. I read that each Map/reduce task run on separate JVMs. But if so, why is variable a getting this weird value of 1229? each reduce task should've called doSomething() only once for every key and final value of "a" should've been 240.

If I try creating a object of util class and call Object.doSomething() (making the methods non-static but keeping "a static"), then I get 240.

2. Am I missing something in my fundamentals of static here?

Comment: What version of hadoop are you using?

Comment: @BinaryNerd Hadoop 2.6.0.2.2.0.0.-2041